# Counting the count of distinct values from two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in data base in which there are corresponding values for the primary key.
I want to count the distinct values from two columns.

I already know one method of using union all and then applying groupby on that resultant table.

```
Select Id,Brand1
into #Temp
from data
union all
Select Id,Brand2
from data

Select ID,Count(Distinct Brand1)
from #Temp
group by ID
```

Same thing we can do in big query also using temp table only.

Sample Table

```
ID  Brand1  Brand2
1    A       B
1    B       C
2    D       A
2    A       D
```

Resultant Table

```
ID  Distinct_Count_Brand
1    3
2    2
```

As you can see in this column Distinct_count_Brand It is counting the unique count of Brand from two columns Brand1 and Brand2.

I already know one way (Basically unpivoting) but want to know if there is some other way around to count unique values from two columns.

Comment: Is your question about sql server or bigquery?

Comment: You can provide solution any of those.

Comment: Ok, I don't know bigquery, but I see you already have an answer that should work.

Comment: Yes i already have answer but i want to know if there is some other way without unpivoting the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, I woud use:

```
Select b.id, count(distinct b.brand)
from data d cross apply
     (values (id, brand1), (id, brand2)) b(id, brand)
group by b.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bedb2b1be21af3fc67072f70072e0d4) is a db<>fiddle.

In BigQuery, the equivalent would be expressed as:

```
select t.id, count(distinct brand)
from t cross join
     unnest(array[brand1, brand2]) brand
group by t.id;
```

Here is a BQ query that demonstrates that this works:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, 'A' as brand1, 'B' as brand2 union all
      select 1, 'B', 'C' union all
      select 2, 'D', 'A' union all
      select 2, 'A', 'D'
     )
select t.id, count(distinct brand)
from t cross join
     unnest(array[brand1, brand2]) brand
group by t.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Was looking for different way and found one.But the second solution will not create table with every brand corresponding to every id because you are doing cross apply.

Comment: @BrownBatman . . . I don't understand your comment.  I've included a BQ query that demonstrates that it does what you are asking for.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know BigQuery's quirks, but perhaps you can just inline the union query:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Brand)
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Brand1 AS Brand FROM data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Brand2 FROM data
) t
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Hi Tim your solution is almost same as mine because you are doing the same thing of joining two tables. Is there any other way of doing like without unpivoting the columns or basically putting all values in a single column. BTW thanks for responding quickly.

Comment: If you find yourself with a very frequent or persistent need to do this query, then I would question whether or not your database is properly normalized.  Ideally, if you had just a single column for all brands, you would not need to use a union query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . This query works in both SQL Server and BigQuery.  I would be inclined to write the logic differently in each database, which is why I also provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just concatenated the two columns like this:

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT( DISTINCT( CONCAT( storeId, '---', userId) ) ) as visits
FROM
  main.reports
GROUP BY
  date
```